# GTK+ 3.0 "No application is registered as handling this file"

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to create an about dialog in my GTK application. The following error appears when I click a link to website:

```
Could not show link
No application is registered as handling this file
```

Here is the code:

```
GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_about_dialog_new();
// some come here
gtk_about_dialog_set_website(GTK_ABOUT_DIALOG(dialog), "http://stackoverflow.com");
// some code here
gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
```

Problem is that there is no default browser set, but how can I set it on windows?

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer for this? Having the same issue in Windows.

Comment: @duncan No, after all these years I'm not even using C/Cpp anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have no default browser set. The XDG spec has some helper tools to set stuff like this. In the xdg-utils package of a linux distro, you will find the xdg-setting command

```
blah@blah:~$ xdg-settings --list
Known properties:
  default-web-browser           Default web browser
blah@blah:~$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
firefox.desktop
```

In GNOME, you can set it by running `gnome-control-center` → "Details" → "Default Apllications" and then setting the browser.

Comment: _That's because you have no default browser set._ Yeah I figured it out myself :) But how to get rid of this error on windows?